# Flask Bable - [jinja2: **/templates/**.html] SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, flask, python-babel, flask-babel

I find the documentation between Flask Babel and Jinja confusing.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbDashboard3$ python run.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 11, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbDashboard3/app/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    app.config.from_pyfile('babel.cfg')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/config.py", line 129, in from_pyfile
    execfile(filename, d.__dict__)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbDashboard3/app/babel.cfg", line 1
    [jinja2: **/templates/**.html]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This this per the docs.

```
[python: **.py]
[jinja2: **/templates/**.html]
extensions=jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_
```

Here is my `__init__.py` file

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.babel import Babel
from config import basedir

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_pyfile('babel.cfg')
babel = Babel(app)
```

This now leaves me with nowhere to go.  How to I resolve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `babel.cfg` file is not inteded as a Flask config file; it is meant to be used with the `pybabel` command line tool *only*:

```
pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -o messages.pot .
```

Remove the `app.config.from_pyfile('babel.cfg')` line from your `__init__.py`. The Flask example at the top of the Flask Babel documentation happens to use `from_pyfile('mysettings.cfg')` but your project already loads it's Flask configuration using `from_object(config)`.